# Requiring a user to be in a role and logged in a route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a route

```js
  {
    path: '/flights_marketers/dashboard',
    name: 'flights_marketers/dashboard',
    meta: { title: 'Flights Marketers Dashboard',requiresAuth: true, rolesAllowed: 'guest,admin,marketer' },
    component: () => import( '../views/backendviews/flights_marketers/flights_marketers_dashboard.vue')
   },
```

that requires a user to be logged in and if not, user is redirected to login page and if logged in and do not have the required role, to be redirected to the Unauthorized access page.

This checks if a user is logged in

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

document.title = to.meta.title
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.state.auth.loggedin_status == 'loggedin') {
        
      next();
      return;
    }
    window.location.replace("/Login");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

and this which does not  work

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title
      if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (store.state.auth.loggedin == 'loggedin' && to.meta.rolesAllowed.split(',').includes(store.state.auth.role) ) {
            
          next();
          return;
        }
        else{
            window.location.replace("/Unauthorized");
        }
        window.location.replace("/Login");
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
```

checks to see if a logged in user has the required role and is logged in. How can i correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `window.location.replace`, use `next({ path, replace: true })`:

```js
// window.location.replace("/Unauthorized");
next({ path: "/Unauthorized", replace: true });

// window.location.replace("/Login");
next({ path: "/Login", replace: true });
```

The logic in your `beforeEach` callback should be similar to this pseudo code:

```js
if (/* route requires auth */) {
  if (/* logged in */) {
    if (/* authorized */) {
      return next()
    } else {
      return next({ path: '/Unauthorized', replace: true })
    }
  } else {
    return next({ path: '/Login', replace: true })
  }
} else {
  return next()
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redirect-to-unauthorized-login-page-c5bj2?file=/src/router.js)